# Get an array dynamicaly from a factory

Tags: arrays, angularjs, dynamic, factory

I'm trying to get information from a factory and trying to print it **dynamic**.
Before I did it like this:

```
<div class="articlePage">
    <h4> {{ posts[0].title  }} </h4> <span style="color: #666;"> {{ posts[0].date }} </span>
    <p> {{ posts[0].text }} </p> {{id}}
</div>
```

But now I said "[0]" so I asked only the first one in the array but from now on it is one page so it need to dynamic.

On my home page I have many posts and when I click on one I want to read the full post on a specific page.

This is how my factory looks like:

```
    App.factory('PostsService', [function () {
    var postsService = {};

    var _posts = [{
            id: 00,
            title: 'Kabinet in hoger beroep tegen klimaatvonnis',
            text: 'Dat bevestigen Haagse bronnen na berichtgeving in dagblad Trouw. Het kabinet zegt tegelijkertijd wel bereid te zijn om extra maatregelen te nemen om de uitstoot van broeikasgassen terug te dringen. Staatssecretaris Mansveld van Milieu maakt naar verluidt dinsdagmiddag bekend hoe het kabinet dat wil doen. De zaak tegen de overheid werd aangespannen door actiegroep Urgenda en negenhonderd klagers. Die stelden dat de Staat zich meer moet inspannen om de CO2-uitstoot in Nederland terug te dringen.',
            date: '28 september 2015'
    },
        {
            id: 01,
            title: '\'Leraren kritisch over passend onderwijs\'',
            text: 'Dat blijkt uit onderzoek van het AD en Duo Onderwijsonderzoek. Door passend onderwijs kunnen leerlingen die meer hulp nodig hebben, vaker terecht in het reguliere onderwijs. Bijna de helft van docenten (47 procent) in het voorgezet onderwijs zegt echter te weinig tijd te hebben om dergelijke jongeren goed te helpen. In het basisonderwijs is dat zelfs 84 procent. Extra handen in de klas staan dan ook op het verlanglijstje van vrijwel alle docenten in het voortgezet onderwijs (84 procent) en het basisonderwijs (99 procent). Ook zegt 98 procent van de leraren op de middelbare school behoefte te hebben aan kleinere klassen, tegenover ongeveer 95 procent van hun collega\'s in het basisonderwijs. Het onderzoek werd uitgevoerd onder 1668 onderwijsmedewerkers, zoals leraren, directeuren en zorgcoördinatoren.',
            date: '15 januari 2015'
    },
        {
            id: 02,
            title: 'Premier Curaçao dient ontslag in',
            text: 'De partij van Asjes, Pueblo Soberano (PS), had eerder op de dag het vertrouwen in de minister-president opgezegd. De partij heeft niet bekendgemaakt waarom het vertrouwen in de premier is opgezegd, maar de PS-fractie botste de afgelopen maanden een aantal keer openlijk met Asjes over verschillende beleidskwesties. Het vertrek van Asjes leidt niet direct tot de val van het kabinet. Een van de meningsverschillen draaide om de steun die de premier bleef geven aan de gevolmachtigde minister van Curaçao in Nederland, Marvelyne Wiels. Zij ligt zwaar onder vuur na het verschijnen van een kritisch rapport van de Curaçaose Ombudsman over haar functioneren. De fractie zou haar niet meer willen steunen. Minister van Volksgezondheid Ben Whiteman is maandagavond door de gouverneur gevraagd de functie van minister-president waar te nemen voor een periode van drie maanden. Whiteman heeft de functie geaccepteerd. Hij zei tegen de pers de gang van zaken rond het vertrek van Asjes te betreuren.',
            date: '31 augustus 2015'
    },
        {
            id: 03,
            title: 'Asscher heeft nog geen akkoord met Marokko over uitkeringen',
            text: 'Desondanks hoopt de bewindsman nog steeds tot een akkoord te komen, schrijft hij dinsdag aan de Tweede Kamer. Het socialezekerheidsverdrag regelt de uitbetaling van Nederlandse uitkeringen voor Marokkaanse-Nederlanders in Marokko. Asscher wil die uitkeringen aanpassen aan het levenspeil in Marokko en dus verlagen. De regering in Rabat voelt hier echter niets voor. Het is de tweede keer dat Asscher moet meldden dat hij niet tot een akkoord is gekomen. Eerder hoopte hij er al op 15 juni uit te zijn. Later verschoof die datum naar 1 september. In de afgelopen periode is intensief overleg gevoerd met Marokko. Tot op heden heeft dit echter nog niet geresulteerd in een akkoord, aldus Asscher. Een nieuwe datum voor een mogelijk akkoord noemt hij niet. Vooral regeringspartij VVD heeft zich hard gemaakt voor aanpassing van het socialezekerheidsverdrag. De Tweede Kamer nam vorig jaar een VVD-motie aan waarin stond dat het verdrag moest worden opgezegd als de onderhandelingen niet snel vruchten zouden afwerpen.',
            date: '02 april 2015'
    }
    ];

    postsService.posts = _posts;

    return postsService;
}
```

I hope you understand my problem if you don't ask something that you need to know I hope that you can help me.

Comment: if you want to display all record in page use `ng-repeat`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <div >Post</div>
  <div ng-repeat="post in posts | filter:filters">
    <h4 ng-click="filters.id = post.id"> {{ post.title  }}</h4>
    <span style="color: #666;"> {{ post.date }} </span>
    <p> {{ post.text }} </p>
  </div>
  <div ng-click="filters.id = ''" ng-if="filters.id == ''">Go Back</div>
</div>
```

Controller

```
app.controller("myCtrl" , function($scope,PostsService) {          
    $scope.posts = PostsService.posts;
    $scope.filters = {};                    
});
```

Refer [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/JbVk04A8xLtHopaB3aye?p=preview).

**Explaination**

Click on the header of the post and then only that post is visible and then a 'Go Back' button is visible to go back to all post page.

The handling is done using a `filters` object which filter only that post on which the `click` is performed.

Comment: Thank you for your time.
I tried it but now when I click on a post it shows all posts on the specific page but I only want to show the one that I clicked

Comment: I need something like {{ post.title where id = 1 }} I know it doesn't work but I need something that way

Comment: @Goldenowner : I have updated the answer!! Hope this may solve your requirement. Sorry for late reply :-)